# Git and TFS Service Mac users

Tags: git, azure-devops

i need some help with understanding TFS Git and Mac.

our graphics development team uses Macs and i would like them to drop all the artwork into our TFS online folders. I believe this can be done by using Git but does that mean they have to use XCode?

is it possible for them to simply drop their files into a folder locally and those will be committed to TFS online.

any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not.  One need not use any IDE integration for Git repositories - and if you don't actually use an IDE then this would certainly be a cumbersome workflow.

Your designers need to merely `git add` the files they've modified then `git commit` them into the repository.

Do note, however, that a Git repository may not be the best mechanism for graphics!  If you have large binary contents that change frequently then your Git repository will contain a copy of each version that has ever been checked in.  This could grow very large!

Comment: ok, that makes sense. any ideas where to get git software for Mac.